# Split large files

Tags: c++, read-write

I am developing a distributed system where in a server will distribute a huge task to clients who would process them and return the result.
Server has to accept huge files with size of the order of 20Gb.

Server has to split this file into smaller pieces and send the path to the clients who in turn would scp the file and process them.

I am using `read` and `write` to perform file splitting which is performing ridiculously slow.

**Code**

```
//fildes - Source File handle
//offset - The point from which the split to be made  
//buffersize - How much to split  

//This functions is called in a for loop   

void chunkFile(int fildes, char* filePath, int client_id, unsigned long long* offset, int buffersize) 
{
    unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc( buffersize * sizeof(unsigned char) );
    char* clientFileName = (char*)malloc( 1024 );
    /* prepare client file name */
    sprintf( clientFileName, "%s%d.txt",filePath, client_id);

    ssize_t readcount = 0;
    if( (readcount = pread64( fildes, buffer, buffersize, *offset ) ) < 0 ) 
    {
            /* error reading file */
            printf("error reading file \n");
    } 
    else 
    {
            *offset = *offset + readcount;
            //printf("Read %ud bytes\n And offset becomes %llu\n", readcount, *offset);
            int clnfildes = open( clientFileName, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY , 0777);

            if( clnfildes < 0 ) 
            {
                    /* error opening client file */
            } 
            else 
            {
                    if( write( clnfildes, buffer, readcount ) != readcount ) 
                    {
                            /* eror writing client file */
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                            close( clnfildes );
                    }
            }
    }

    free( buffer );
    return;
}
```

1. Is there any faster way to split files?
2. Is there any way client can access its chunk in the file without using scp (read without transfer)?

I am using C++. I am ready to use other languages if they can perform faster.

Comment: Try assembly if you are not satisfied with C++ speed...

Comment: But seriously there could be something wrong with your code. You might need to paste it here so we know how to improve. There is nothing we can do if we don't know what you are doing

Comment: Seeing the questionably-slow code would *greatly* assist in analyzing your problem. It could be anything from a slow net link, to a horrid algorithm implementation, both, or something completely different.

Comment: Compression if feasible was considered I hope.

Comment: What are the size of the split files, size of the chunk used to read/write ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I am yet to finalize optimum chunk size.

Comment: malloc in c++ :/ ... memleak of `clientFileName`, I assume that `pread64` does an unneeded `seek` if you call this function in sequence. You may read/write by chunk smaller than the final size to avoid to allocate huge memory. `read`/`write` may return size smaller than `buffersize` without an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the file in the reach of a webserver and then use `curl` from the clients

```
curl --range 10000-20000 http://the.server.ip/file.dat > result
```

would get 10000 bytes (from 10000 to 20000)

If the file is highly redundant and the network is slow probably using compression could help speeding up the transfer a lot. For example executing

```
nc -l -p 12345 | gunzip > chunk
```

on the client and then executing

```
dd skip=10000 count=10000 if=bigfile bs=1 | gzip | nc client.ip.address 12345
```

on the server you can transfer a section doing a gzip compression on the fly without the need of creating intermediate files.

### EDIT

A single command to get a section of a file from a server using compression over the network is

```
ssh server 'dd skip=10000 count=10000 bs=1 if=bigfile | gzip' | gunzip > chunk
```

Comment: I am interested in your second solution `nc`. If my understanding is correct, the `dd` command you mentioned would skip 10000 bytes from the `bigfile` and take 10000 chunks of 1 byte and `netcat` to the client. Is that right?

Comment: I would like to have clients pull data than server pushing to clients. I have multiple clients running on the same ip. Is this achievable using nc? I can make server let the client know which offset it has to take data from.

Comment: @cppcoder: you can use different ports (I used 12345 in my example) for different clients on the same ip and the server could start the client command itself using ssh.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid server doing any command `dd` and the client himself to take the file from the server using `nc`?

Comment: I need this because, I am using a multicast communication from server to client. I do not want to make server perform command for each client individually.

Comment: @cppcoder: of course the clients could start the listening process and then use ssh on the server to start `dd` to get the data, but they would need a way to find what is the section they need to process e.g. by invoking a server program that gives them the section or that starts the `dd` command directly.

Comment: I can make clients know what is the `skip`, `count`, `bs` values.Not an issue. How can a client ssh to server and do `dd`?

Comment: I can google to find out how to do that. But my concern is whether it would be a bottle neck to do ssh? I might have 1000's of clients doing ssh to server and running `dd`.

Comment: @cppcoder: `ssh` can run arbitrary commands on another machine, e.g. `ssh user@server.ip.address 'dd skip=12345 ... '`. Note however that I'm not sure if you can get a single server compressing and sending huge amounts of data to thousands and thousands clients at the same time, may be it would be better to use at least a three levels scheme for that (server sends to second-level servers that in turn sends to third-level processing clients). The bottleneck is probably the bandwidth but hard to say without real numbers. In such a problem seems to me that `ssh` options is the smallest issue :-D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37774/discussion-between-cppcoder-and-6502)

Answer (score 1):

Is rsync over SSH with the --partial an option?
Then you might not need to split the files either since you can just continue if the transfer is interrupted.

Are the file split sizes known in advance or are they split along some marker in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can deposit file onto NFS shared device, and client can mount that device in RO-mode. Thereafter, client can open file, and use mmap() or pread() for read it's slice (piece of file). By this way, to client, will be transferred just needed part of the file.